# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to call an .exe from the windows service. Task of that .exe is to generate an output file while displaying a confirmation message. But real scenario of what happens, is when service starts the exe the file shows in the task manager but didn't create the output.

Comment: Did you perhaps misspell the name of the exe?

Comment: actually i want to call exe file that creates out put

Comment: check if the account used to run the service has permissions etc to run and create the output in the folder (folder permssions)

Comment: yes.it was allready given.when executes exe file mannualy output was created.

Comment: when you run the service which account does it use? does this account have write permissions on folder?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody found humor in my comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because service is not running under you user. That is why you can't see the "output message" (which I guess is some message box or anything dialog based) but you can see the process in task manager only when "show processes from all users" check box is checked.

If you need to see some output, at least for test period store information in file, but make sure that the user under which service is running has appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely an unhandled exception in the second exe that prevents it from creating the file.
One of the common problem is file permissions, check that the service identity is authorized to create file in the target folder (especially if it is a network share).

You can also have a look in the event log and see if there is something related to your service.